# UITableViewCell with Custom Style

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView with custom cell with **identifier** on it. added and styled with the **interface builder** in the **Prototype Cells** section.

At the beginning Cells styles as expected:

[image]

But, when user tap on any cell the following happen to the 3rd cell from the bottom:

[image]

**Notes**

1. Selection is set to Single Selection on tableview in interface builder.
2. Accessory for TableCell set by default to CheckMark in interface builder.
3. I call reloadData on tableView when didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called.
4. I removed the CheckMark Accessory from interface builder and removed the code that handles it appearance. But, this didn't solve the problem.

**Sample below**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Team *team = [[teams objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TeamCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *teamName = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:10];
    UIImageView *teamImage = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:20];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeHandler:)];
    [gestureRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)];
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

    cell.tag = indexPath.section * team_index_modular + indexPath.row;

    teamName.text = team.team_name;
    [teamImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:team.team_image]];

    if (selected_index == indexPath.row && selected_section == indexPath.section)
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    else
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: `cell.tag = indexPath.section * team_index_modular + indexPath.row;` this line of code makes me to think that then you're retrieving that cells back (not in cellForRow)?

Comment: I think that's it. I thought I handled that smart. I will modify it to become indexPath.section+1 and let you know.

Comment: I removed that line and it worked! It seems that system is using the cell.tag to handle something and I am playing with its value!! please, add that as an answer. I will accept it.

Comment: hm, if tag is used only for swiping, then that should not make problem

Comment: solution was by (indexPath.section+1) * team_index_modular + indexPath.row. when section is zero. tag for that row will equal to 10. which is equal to another view tag. UILabel *teamName = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:10];

Comment: interesting :) that's cool